# Запятые при вводном слове

Tags: пунктуация

"Но пришла революция - и в одночасье всё это ушло от него". Отделяется ли запятыми "в одночасье". Почему? Спасибо.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

"Но пришла революция - и в одночасье всё это ушло от него".

В одночасье = быстро, т.е.является обстоятельством образа действия (как?), а вводные слова не являются членами предложения. Запятых нет.

Answer (score 0):

Не отделяется. Какое же это вводное слово? Это обычное обстоятельство. Вот только какое... Ушло (когда?) или (как?)

Comment: Поскольку Вы делаете вид, что Вам непонятно, поясняю. Минус - за безответственное отношение к ответу. Если не знаете, какое это обстоятельство, то вам лучше не отвечать на серьезные вопросы. Вы даже вопрос не можете толком поставить к члену предложения, а беретесь менторствовать.

Comment: А вы знаете? И уверены, что *всегда* можете *однозначно* определить тип обстоятельства? Тогда вы в десять раз безответственнее меня.

Comment: Я уверен, что не желаю отвечать на вопросы, которые Вы задаете подобным тоном.

Answer (score 0):

Нет. Здесь запятых обычно не требуется. Если автор не настаивает на каком-то особом использовании (как вводного, например, или интонационного), то обособлять тут нечего. Можно было бы обособить как уточнение, но очень сомнительно, что "в одночасье" может быть уточнение для "всё".

Comment: Хочу объясниться. Ставлю минус не так, как вы, трусливо и без объяснений, а за удивительное по неграмотности высказывание: "Можно было бы обособить как уточнение".

Comment: Да сколько угодно. "Объяснения" Ваши только доказывают, что ставите вы по причинам личной обиды, не умея или не удосужившись вдуматься в смысл мной сказанного.

Comment: Вот эти слова ("личная обида") вы должны обратить как раз к себе. Ну, опростоволосились разок, что же теперь на весь свет-то злобу затаивать? ))

Comment: С истериками - идите в чат. Мне Вы больше не интересны.